# junit ClassNotFoundException in ScalaIDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I've uploaded my scala project to github

> https://github.com/jeesim2/Scala210

Problem is

- I need to use scala 2.10 (due to spark 1.6 compatiblilty) 
  but on ScalaIDE(latest version) I can not run junit test.

Run Unit Test

[image: Run Junit On Scala-IDE]
But Fails with,

```
Class not found Junit
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Junit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

When I change Scala version to 2.11 in pom.xml, then It works.
(I commented working properties in pom.xml )

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.10.6</scala.version> <-- not work
    <!-- <scala.version>2.11.5</scala.version> --> <-- work
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>  <-- not work
        <version>2.2.6</version> <-- not work
        <!-- <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId> -->  <-- work
        <!-- <version>3.0.0</version> -->  <-- work
    </dependency>
```

Why I can not run Scala 2.10's Junit on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Scala IDE 3.0.3 works for me.

http://scala-ide.org/download/prev-stable.html

I think newer version's not stable for 2.10.x

:D